# Custom Shapes from sprites

Tags: shapes, netlogo

I've been working in a project lately and it's almost done so I was wondering if there is an easy way to make an sprite into a turtle shape. e.g.: I'd like to use a pokémon sprite for my turtle. But Turtle Shape Editor errors when I try to load the .png file.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.

At least, unless you modify NetLogo yourself (hard), or unless you write an extension (easier). And even if you write an extension, you can't really make turtle shapes actually do what you want; you have to fake it. See discussion at https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues/509, where I write, "consider writing an extension primitive that renders a raster shape directly to the drawing layer..."

It's an often-requested feature; we've just never gotten around to it.